# Verifying digital signatures in PDF documents

Tags: pdf, cryptography, adobe, itext, digital-signature

I'm trying to verify PDF's digital signatures.

I know that when a PDF is signed, a byterange is defined, the certificates get embedded, and from what i've read, the signed message digest and the timestamp are also stored in the PDF.

I already can extract the certificates and validate them.
Now I'm trying to validate the pdf's integrity and my problem is I don't know where the signed message digest is located.

In this sample signed pdf from Adobe (http://blogs.adobe.com/security/SampleSignedPDFDocument.pdf), i can clearly identify the digest since it is down below the embedded certificates: /DigestMethod/MD5/DigestValue/ (line 1520).

But that PDF sample seems to be from 2009, and I suspect the message digest is stored in a different way now, because I signed a PDF with Adobe Reader and also with iText, and I can't find any message digest field like the previous one.
Can someone tell if the digests are now stored in a different way? Where are they located?

Anyway, for now I'm using that sample document from Adobe, and trying to verify its integrity.
I'm getting the document's bytes to be signed acording to the specified byterange, and digesting them with MD5 algorithm, but the digest value I get doesn't match with the one from the message digest field...
Am I doing something wrong? Is the digest also signed with the signer's private key?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you using the [PDF book (standard)](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) as reference? Are you trying to create a CMS (PKCS#7 format) style signature yourself?

Comment: To me it sounds like the op only knows the non-CMS pdf signatures yet.

Comment: @mkl Ah, that goes a long way to explaining the issue. I've never dealt with PDF signatures, but I read standards when I come across them.

Comment: Ok, so, in CMS signatures the digest value is stored along with the rest of the DER structure. The second question remains unanswered though. I compared the content of an original PDF file with its signed 'version', and realized it changes a lot after the signature process (it doesn't just add a pkcs7 object to the file).
So, if I hash the content of the signed PDF file, according to the byterange (therefore excluding the pkcs7 object), it will not match the original one because the content changes in a lot of different places. How can I obtain the same digest value hashing the signed pdf?

Comment: I guess the only thing you can do is try to find out what is added, and remove the items, restoring the original (or, at least, hash the original adjusted bytes). That will be a lot of work though.

Comment: @wolvz you might want to read [this answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35121/a-standard-way-to-manually-add-a-digital-signature-to-a-pdf-file/35131#35131). As you can read there, you don't use the digest of the original pdf anywhere. You first prepare the pdf for signing (which introduces all the differences you found) and only then calculate the hash, sign it, and finally insert the signature into the prepared pdf.

Comment: I see, thanks. For testing, I removed the PKCS7 object manually from the file, erasing Contents, leaving it like this .../Contents<>/Filter/Adobe.PPKLite/... Then I hashed the file (obviously using the same algorithm) and got a digest. The value still doesn't match the digest in the signed file. I also tried other possibilities, like /Contents/Filter, etc.

Comment: To explain for the sample you use please supply a link to it and explain which digest you found and which digest you calculated.

Comment: @mkl thanks for your patience. This is the pdf sample: http://bit.ly/1oR8XHK . I extracted the Contents value, and used an ASN.1 parser to check what's the digest value, obtaining http://bit.ly/1kcbZFK . The digest value is "77908DA519EF898F66166CC0ACE6B82461A6DE87BE00BA5A702EAB0C263678BE", correct? Then I erased the Contents value from the PDF, digested the whole document with SHA-256 algoritm, obtaining "C2F281B16FB896E39BE7CFA2A4ABE3C8DDDDA81FE284CFB2BD22933DA3A429B2", which is different.

Comment: *I erased the Contents value from the PDF* - Did you remove that value including the leading '<' and the trailing '>'? These brackets are part of the value, not merely the hex encoded bytes.

Comment: Ah, I see from your former comment that you manually erased the signature bytes and got `/Contents<>/Filter/Adobe.PPKLite/...`; as mentioned in my previous comment, this is wrong: The whole value of the **Contents** key has to be removed, i.e. you should hash `/Contents/Filter/Adobe.PPKLite/...`. That been said, though, even if I erase as incorrectly as you say you did, I get a different digest value: c4378cf8f4cdf982a5a44007c734756df98e70f6ab037e525ae59be46a9588c4. Thus, something else in your manual erasing or your hashing process is erroneous. Did you e.g. use a normal text editor to erase?

Comment: @mkl, I finally got the correct hash value! I guess the problem was the fact I was using a normal text editor to erase... I got the file content's bytes according to the byterange and hashed it (code: http://bit.ly/1l0GSwZ). Thank you very much. If you suggest an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are numerous details to get right when calculating the hash for integrated PDF signatures, among them:

- Extract the correct bytes from the PDF to hash. The **ByteRange** tells you exactly which byte ranges are signed. To be accepted in modern signing contexts, the ranges must cover the whole PDF file revision with the exception of the value of **Contents**.

  Beware, the value of **Contents** *includes* the the leading '<' and the trailing '>' brackets.
- Don't use a regular text editor or text processing instructions (like `readln` or `writeln`) to process PDFs. PDFs are binary in nature, even if they look textual to the naked eye. Copying PDF parts using such text related operations most likely changes them in details, definitively breaking the signature hash value.

When in doubt, don't guess but read the specification. A copy of ISO 32000-1 has been made available by Adobe [here](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), and much you need to know about the PDF format to start processing them can be found there and in other public standards referenced in there. A very short introduction to integrated PDF signatures can be found in [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35121/a-standard-way-to-manually-add-a-digital-signature-to-a-pdf-file/35131#35131) and documents referenced from there.

Comment: Good day, How to find those ByteRange or Contents properties programmatically? I could not find any info about it.

Comment: @BekaBot you should use a sufficiently versatile general purpose pdf library. There are such libraries available for all major languages and runtime environments. If you do not want to use such a third party library, simply follow the link in my answer to the copy of ISO 32000-1 made freely available by Adobe.